# Call a JavaScript Function from Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a basic Flask app running, with the code in main.py hosting the flask app. I also have an index.html file that will get text input from the user. I can use `request.form` to access the input, and I can work with it successfully. However, I encountered a problem.

I need to call a JavaScript function that opens a new tab with a certain website. For example, if the user types in Wikipedia, I need to tell JavaScript to `window.open("https://www.wikipedia.org")`. The problem is, I can't find any working way to call a JavaScript function from a Flask application.

And before you mark this question as duplicate, the answer to the one Stack Overflow question on this I found did not even involve flask, and the other answer (using webbrowser.open_new_tab) opened the new tab on the server machine, not on the client machine (the one where the website is actually being accessed).

I know you can call a Python function from JavaScript, but is it possible to do it the other way?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: So you want to pass `flask` input variable inside that `javascript` function?

Comment: No, I want to call a JavaScript function (that opens a new tab) from a flask function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by passing the url as a query string to the url containing the javascript. You can acces the query string in javascript and use it in the function that opens the window.

Comment: I am a bit new to JavaScript... exactly how would you access the parameters of the current website?

Comment: ```let urlForNewWindow = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('url')```
Lets say your url is {base_url}/index.html, you can add this to set the 'url' query parameter to http://wikipedia.com, ```?url=http://wikipedia.com```. So the final url will look something like this: ```{base_url}/index.html?url=http://wikipedia.com```
the ```urlForNewWindow``` variable will be equal to ```http://wikipedia.com```.